# ConstraintLayout - Match another view's constraints but add margin to make it larger

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a TextView, whose width and height is resolved at runtime depending on the text body provided to it. Then I have another View, that needs to exactly match the TextView's top/bottom/start/end constraints, but 16dp larger. Here's what I tried:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:text="Test title"
    />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/title"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/title"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/title"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    />
```

The 16dp layout_margin makes the View 16dp *smaller* than the TextView in all 4 directions, whereas I want to make it 16dp *larger*. The only solution I've found so far is to declare 4 Spaces (each one 16dp away from one of the constraints), then constrain the View to those Spaces, which honestly seems overkill for what should be a simple layout rule. Do constraint layouts provide an easier way of achieving this?

Comment: If you know the dimensions at runtime why dont you give the same width and height to view more 16dp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the *View*, set the margins at `-16dp` as follows:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="-16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/title"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/title"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/title" />
```

Do not set `android:layout_margin="-16dp"`. It will not work.

I am using *ConstraintLayout* version *2.1.0*. Negative margins are not permitted with earlier versions.

In this image, I have rearranged the views and set background colors to highlight the extent of the views.

[image]

Comment: Upon reflection, I don't think this is the intended behavior but a byproduct of the introduction of negative margins. The fact that `android:layout_margin` doesn't work but specifying each margin individually does work gives me pause. I think that this is something that can easily break in the future and get a "will not fix" if reported (just guessing here.)